Ошибка отправки сообщения и подключения к 587 порту через spring boot
Мне нужно написать сервис для отправки писем, но сколько источников я не просматривал ничего не выходит и вылетает с данной ошибкой:

"Mail server connection failed. Failed messages:
org.eclipse.angus.mail.util .MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to
host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;\n nested exception
is:\n\tjava.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect".

Подскажите пожалуйста, может я где-то что-то упустил. Вот мой сервис, который встроен в другой через DI с помощью интерфейса, ошибок там быть не может:
@Service
public class EmailService implements IEmailService{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);
    private final JavaMailSender _javaMailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String sender;

    public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        _javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }


    @Override
    public ServiceResponse<String> sendEmail(String recipientEmail, String subject, String message) {
        var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<String>();
        try {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = _javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(sender);
            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(recipientEmail);
            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessageHelper.setText(message);
            _javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            serviceResponse.data = null;
            serviceResponse.success = true;
            serviceResponse.message = String.format("Security code for %s successfully sent to your email.", subject);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error sending email: {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
            serviceResponse.data = null;
            serviceResponse.success = false;
            serviceResponse.message = ex.getMessage();
        }
        return serviceResponse;
    }

application.yml:
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: myemail@gmail.com
    password: mypassword
    port: 587
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          starttls:
            enable: true
          auth: true

Пакет с pom.xml:
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>


О, я недавно похожий вопрос задал)) Но у вас, как я вижу, SMTP-сервер от gmail. Вы используете обычный пароль от почты или специальный для приложения?

Специальный, сгенерированный через app passwords в gmail

Интересно. Если вдруг найдёте решение этой проблемы - напишите здесь в качестве ответа, или в комментариях. Я на английском стеке вот что нашёл: "The reason was my internet provider. I tried the same code in antoher one and it worked!" - но сам не пробовал на другом провайдере пока.

Я на подобный вопрос получил ответ в стиле - "пропингуй smtp сервер", и дополнительно -3 к рейтингу топика :)

Ага, вижу) Да, все решения, которые вам там подсказали, у меня тоже не работают.

напишите, пожалуйста, в случае обнаружения решения проблемы

А curl -ом не пробовали подключиться с вашими параметрами? Там хоть развёрнутый вывод можно посмотреть

На 587 порт не получится никак коннектится, надо использовать IMAP.

IMAP используется для приёма писем, а не для отправки...

Проблема решилась путем замены интернет-провайдера (изначально не работало, т.к подключился к Wi-Fi другой сети с вставленным патч-кордом текущей сети (не знаю, проблема винды или самой сетевой карты, что она не смогла переключить сигнал, но после переключения на другую сеть и полного отключения от предыдущей smtp сразу же встал и заработал)).

Круто) Получается, в итоге оказалось как и у того человека с англоязычного стека, который тоже поменял провайдер и всё заработало. Можете тогда отметить ответ как принятый)
